# Proverb? "When you have completed 95 percent of your journey, you are only halfway there."

Tags: proverbs

Around the Internet, "When you have completed 95 percent of your journey, you are only halfway there" is floating around as a Japanese proverb.

A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBD_enJP903JP903&biw=2327&bih=1180&ei=3j81X5KpGcbmwQOB7rSIAQ&q=japanese+proverb+%22only+halfway+there%22&oq=japanese+proverb+%22only+halfway+there%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQA1CJGFiiG2CnHGgAcAB4AIABdIgBiwWSAQMwLjaYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiSkL6upJjrAhVGc3AKHQE3DREQ4dUDCAw&uact=5) for `Japanese proverb "only halfway there"` gives 12,000+ hits and several Instagram-ready quote photos.  None of the first 100 hits cite a Japanese source.

What is the actual proverb in Japanese?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the standard version is [百里を行く者は九十を半ばとす](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E7%99%BE%E9%87%8C%E3%82%92%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%8F%E8%80%85%E3%81%AF%E4%B9%9D%E5%8D%81%E3%82%92%E5%8D%8A%E3%81%B0%E3%81%A8%E3%81%99/) "Who travels a hundred [*li*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li_(unit)) calls ninety a half", because this is the original form attested in [a Chinese chronicle](https://ctext.org/zhan-guo-ce/wei-qin-wang#n49690).

There is another quote from a Japanese writer [Ryūnosuke Akutagawa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ry%C5%ABnosuke_Akutagawa), which says [百里の半ばを九十九里とする](https://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000879/files/43751_27955.html) "assumes the half of a hundred *li* to be ninety-nine *li*".

Either way, I could not find an exact Japanese source that tells the number "95%". And I doubt that it exists.